# Specify encryption key during CLI install?

Tags: magento2.2, installation, encryption-key

Is it possible to set the Magento encryption key when using the `magento setup:install` command for unattended installation?

There does not appear to be a specific option for the encryption key.  I tried adding `--magento-init-params="crypt[key]=$encryption_key"`, but no luck.

In theory I could use `sed` or similar to edit the encryption key immediately after installing, but I would prefer to avoid this approach if possible.

Using Magento 2.2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible.
try:

`magento setup:install --key="YOURKEYHERE" ... OTHER ARGS ...`

Comment: I actually found this and tried it, but I got an error.  As I recall it was something along the lines of `Encryption key cannot be longer than 32 bytes`.  Is there a particular way the key has to be formatted?  I was just specifying it in hex as it appears in `env.php`.

Comment: It worked for me—I just used an ASCII key like the one autogenerated by Magento which was exactly 32 characters.